# How to implement tab functionality and handle pop ups with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I'm lil new to iOS development and took up really a tough(of course to me) task to create a web browser. I'm using `UIWebView` and now I'm struck in handling `popups` to my app.

Can any has Some idea about implementing popups and creating new tabs when webpage ask page to open in new tab?

Please guys help.

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: I can use `UIWebViewNavigationType` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method of `UIWebView` but Can't handle popup with this as well

Comment: I don't know how to identify html `a` tag with target `_blank` @UsmanMaqbool